# How to save dynamic Groupbox & Checkedlistbox items

Tags: vb.net

I'm using this code to create GroupBox reading from file sQue.txt and I'm populating CheckedListBox reading from file sObj.txt. When the Form loads, multiple GB are created (based on count of entries from sQue.txt) and in each GB is incorporated a CLB with items from sObj.txt. Here is the working code:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles        MyBase.Load
    Dim NewForm2 As New Form2
    NewForm2.Show()
    Dim sObj() As String = File.ReadAllLines("C:\temp\sQue.txt")
    Dim sQue() As String = File.ReadAllLines("C:\temp\sObj.txt")
    For Each s As String In sObj
        Me.Controls.Add(MakeNewGB(s, sQue))
    Next

End Sub
End Class
Public Module Module1
Friend WithEvents NewGB As System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
Friend WithEvents NewCLB As System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox
Public NextColumn As Integer = 0
Public Function MakeNewGB(lbl As String, clbItems() As String) As GroupBox
    NewGB = New System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox()
    NewCLB = New System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox()
    NewGB.SuspendLayout()
    'GroupBox1
    '
    NewGB.Controls.Add(NewCLB)
    NewGB.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(NextColumn, 0)
    NewGB.Name = lbl
    NewGB.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(126, 210)
    NewGB.TabIndex = 0
    NewGB.TabStop = False
    NewGB.Text = lbl
    '
    'CheckedListBox1
    '
    NewCLB.FormattingEnabled = True
    NewCLB.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(6, 19)
    NewCLB.Name = "clb" + lbl
    NewCLB.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(103, 184)
    NewCLB.TabIndex = 0
    NewCLB.Items.AddRange(clbItems)
    NextColumn += NewGB.Size.Width + 10
    Return NewGB
End Function
End Module
```

After the form loads the user selects some items from each CLB. There is a button on the form. When button is clicked I want to save selected CLB items from each CLBs against their respective GB in a text file.

How can it be done?

Comment: any comment on my answer?

Answer (score 0):

• You want to handle a button click event

• Use either a streamwriter or file.write to record the selections that have been made

• You want to use something like the below for the selections

```
for each gpx as groupbox in me
    for each rbx as radiobox in gpx.controls
        if control.gettype is gettype(radiobox) then
            if rbx.selected = true then
                'write to a stringbuilder or something
            end if
        end if
    next
next
```

Go write some more code and let us know how you get on :)